# Android - Detecting if image has been datestamped

Tags: android, image, algorithm, image-processing

I'm developing an image processing app, which has some filters, and what I want to do is to remember which photos were datestamped using my app, to exclude it from selection when the user choses this filter again.

Since it's my app the one which is datestamping the photo, I know the font size and the location of it (can be one of the 4 corners of the image), and the color is customizable by the user, so I can't rely on that.

Right now I'm using a database and EXIF metadata for this purpose, but I want my app to be able to still recognize a photo as datestamped when the user sends it via WhatsApp or similar services, and by doing that all metadata is lost, so I can't rely on EXIF.

A solution I thought about was to encode some info in the image pixels, such as storing in the red values the ASCII characters of the initials of my app, but when compressing the photo in order to send it, the color info wasn't exactly preserved, and due to that, my algorithm failed. I also tried setting the corners of the image to a color value relative to the top left corner, but this failed too.

I also tried OCR using Tesseract on the specified image region, but it failed many times (if the background was very bright, for example).

So right now I believe the solution must be trying to locate the datestamp within the image. For this purpose, given I know the font size and exact location, should I go for each number and try to recognize it, or simply count the characters? The problems with this solutions is that maybe they will throw false positives.

So, for sure, I'm not asking about an algorithm, nor a working implementation. 
What I want instead is only some advice on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: The term "steganography" may lead to interesting search results.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but my images are JPEG and they can be subsampled